# JavaScript alert before closing the tab

Tags: javascript

This is my JavaScript code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
        if (e) {
            e.returnValue = 'Any unsaved work is going to loose!';
        }
        // For Safari
        return 'Any unsaved work is going to loose!';
    };
```

This code works perfectly when I try to close the tab. But the problem is, it also gives alert even when I try to navigate to another page of my site.

What could possibly the generic JS code that only shows alert if and only if user attempts to close the tab?

Comment: You could unbind event if clicking any anchor inside your current page but you cannot handle case where user uses address bar to navigate and anyway you cannot handle case where a hurrican strikes user house

Comment: "Lose" not "loose", unless you expect unsaved work is overly permiscuous.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no pure "Close" event in javascript. *onunload* & *onbeforeunload* is best thing that you can do.

By-effect is that these events are triggered on navigation and back-forward browser buttons. You can try to use (e.clientY < 0) condition to filter navigation on your page.

Comment: User can close tab using any keyboard shortcut or even just by shutting down computer. But that's said, you answer correctly the question imho

Comment: @A.Wolff sorry, this code does not work when the electricity is turned off in the home of users too :-)

Comment: Ya, exactly! :)  There is no reliable way to handle OP's expected behaviour, that's the answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

then check  the window.location if has been changed.

Comment: the location changed once the redirection is done so it is too late

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
   if (document.location.href.indexOf('?x=hostname') > -1) {
         e = e || window.event;
        // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
        if (e) {
            e.returnValue = 'Any unsaved work is going to loose!';
        }
        // For Safari
        return 'Any unsaved work is going to loose!';
}
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out the the e.target if you think that e.target is good to go do nothing like

`if (e.target != myATagsOrButtons){`
.... Insert your code

Also another thing is you can have a if isWorking variable set to true if they have entered stuff into the form at which point if they entered stuff into the form then navigate that could be bad for them anyway.

`<input type='text' onkeydown='isUpdating()'>` then check to make sure updating.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try adding a condition where you check if the user is navigating away from the domain and if so raise an alert

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e && window.location.indexOf("www.mysite.com") > -1) {

        e.returnValue = 'Any unsaved work is going to loose!';
    }
    // For Safari
    return 'Any unsaved work is going to loose!';
};
```

Comment: And then why don't you post it as comment? :)

Comment: I thought of doing that. But SO says I should use a comment to ask for more information and suggestions to improve the question. Anyway, I am improving my answer now